# Accessing repository pattern through one more layer called service in Laravel

Tags: laravel, service, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I have created one repository layer in my project which is perfectly accessible through controller method using interface. Now What I want to add, is a service layer. that means I want all controller method operations will be done through the service. So I created one file inside the service folder and I tried to get the access of repository functions through service.

There I have crated one

Constructor for repository access .. but I am getting an error

```
public function __construct(IFamilyRepository $familyRepository){
            $this->$familyRepository = $familyRepository;    // getting error on this line
    }

    public function testRepository(){
        $this->$familyRepository->getAllGrandfather();
        return "null";
    }
```

I am getting error :

```
ErrorException in FamilyService.php line 19:
Object of class App\Repositories\Eloquent\FamilyRepository could not be converted to string
in FamilyService.php line 19
at HandleExceptions->handleError('4096', 'Object of class App\Repositories\Eloquent\FamilyRepository could not be converted to string', 'D:\files\xampp\htdocs\laravel\dolovers-project-nayeb-moshai\app\Services\FamilyService.php', '19', array('familyRepository' => object(FamilyRepository))) in FamilyService.php line 19
at FamilyService->__construct(object(FamilyRepository))
at ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(array(object(FamilyRepository))) in Container.php line 817
at Container->build('App\Services\FamilyService', array()) in Container.php line 656
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access class variables, you need to do `$this->some_var`, not `$this->$some_var`. In the latter case, PHP thinks you're trying to use the string value of `$some_var`, and it can't - so that's why it's complaining about not being able to convert to string.

Just changing that should work right away, assuming your other code is correct.

```
public function __construct(IFamilyRepository $familyRepository){
    $this->familyRepository = $familyRepository;
}

public function testRepository(){
    $this->familyRepository->getAllGrandfather();
    return "null";
}
```

(Also, as a beside - and you know this better than me - should it be `IFamilyRepository`, not `FamilyRepository`?)

Comment: First part is my bad. Thanks a lot for your quick help. That was awesome. Now about the second matter, Is not it better to fetch the repository using Interface even if it is from inside a service ? Please give your feedback. Thanks !

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. To be honest, I'm not sure what the better option would be, so I do not want to advise on that. But I'm glad you got it working!